# problem with KeyGuardManager

Tags: android

I am trying to use the KeyGuardManager to unlock the phone easily.
so far no problems the phone is unlocked and all is good. However when this code is executed later I notice my phone is behaving weirdly. until a I see the following message in the Logcat file :

```
WindowManagerService.mKeyguardTokenWatcher: cleaning up leaked reference
```

meaning as far as I can tell the reference to the key-guard was leaked. I have no idea why this would happen especially as I cannot see a method which seems to safely dispose of the keyguard lock.

The code that aquaired the lock looks like this:

```
// use KeyGuardManager to automaticly unlock the device
    KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock kgl = kgm.newKeyguardLock("BusSnooze");

    if (kgm.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
        kgl.disableKeyguard();
```

Anyone know why this is happening? 
thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I soulved this by using:

```
kgm.exitKeyguardSafely()
```