# How to dismiss lock screen?

Tags: android, locking, screen

in my case, I just start other activity to remove lock screen.
However, I saw any app to dismiss lock screen and that is really smooth.
I think the way is different with me.. 
plz~ tell me how to dismiss lock screen~
and how do i use keyguard to do that?

in advance, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the keyguard, then you want to take a look at the [KeyguardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) class. You can get an instance of it like this:

```
 KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908337/problem-with-keyguardmanager) for some additional code on how to disable it.

If you're talking about the *lock* screen, where the user has to enter a password -- I don't think it's possible to bypass this.