# Resource leak when using KeyGuardManager

Tags: android, resource-leak

I am trying to use the KeyGuardManager and KeyguardLock to unlock the phone but it only works the first few times and when I kill my application I get:

`WindowManagerService.mKeyguardTokenWatcher: cleaning up leaked reference`

This problem is probably related to the issue [problem with KeyGuardManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908337/problem-with-keyguardmanager) but I can not find the mentioned *exitKeyguardSafely()* in the [Android KeyguardManager API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html). Instead of *exitKeyguardSafely()* i tried using *exitKeyguardSecurely()* to no avail.

Please help!

```
private final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

private void unlock() {
   KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
   KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(LOG_TAG);  
   lock.disableKeyguard();
   keyguardManager.exitKeyguardSecurely(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the KeygardLock is a semaphore. Make sure to call *reenableKeyguard()* as many times as *disableKeyguard()* and there is no warning of resource leak.