# Alternatives for unlocking the screen

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that needs to unlock the phone in a certain moment, I know this can be done by using the KeyguardManager, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908337/problem-with-keyguardmanager) is a way for doing this, but I'm using API 16 and AndroidLint tells me that this is deprecated. So, is there any NEW way of handling this in the newest APIs?.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the KeyguardManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)?

Comment: Just because it's deprecated - does not mean it can't be used IMO. Android must be backwards compatible.  I would just test it on a real device or a few of them.

Comment: I'm just asking for better/newest ways of doing this, I never said it can't be used IMO.